# How to handle parent and child pages?

Tags: php, loop, pages, post-content

I want to list episodes of a series I am making of instructional videos with content.

The patent page "series" will list episodes weekly. Ie: episodes 1, 2, etc.

I'm thinking to setup a template to loop through the series parent page to display the episodes children content in a loop.

Then on each series page there will be 3 panels.
A long one with the video and other episodes thumbnails, one on the left and one on the iught with content.

Just trying to work out how to display the children > children post content as above.

Problem 1: displaying related thumbnails to other children?

Problem 2: displaying the 3 panels. Do I set these up as individual children elements? If so, how can I style each one differently as it loops through?

Any code examples would be amazing! Unless there's a plugin for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem 2: displaying the 3 panels. Do I set these up as individual children elements? If so, how can I style each one differently as it loops through?

There are only 3 items. Don't loop through them. Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to place them in an array and then step through each array item:

```
$panels = get_posts( array() );
```

Fill the `array()` with the arguments to get those posts. Now $panels is an array of post objects. Step through them:

```
// First panel
// Do stuff with $panels[0]

// Second panel
// Do stuff with $panels[1]

// Third panel
// Do stuff with $panels[2]
```

To set up the post for use with [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags), use the [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) WordPress function. For example, to echo the post content for the first panel use something like this:

```
global $post;

// First panel
// Do stuff with $panels[0]
$post = $panels[0];
setup_postdata( $post );
echo the_content;
```

After all posts are done reset the from the main query:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

See [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) and [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) for more examples and explanations.

For post thumbnails, read the codex article on [Post Thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) for settings, details and examples.

Comment: Thanks so much @charlesclarkson. Exactly what I needed. Can you also update the answer to show how I would get the post content with each object? And how can I display the thumbnails of each other child>child in the sidebar? Thank you again!

Comment: See the edit above.